# Selenium WebDriver: Any tutorial available for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to start writing tests with Selenium WebDriver and JavaScript. The problem is that I searched for a tutorial, where I would have an overview of element locators, commands, verify commands for elements, clicks, inputting values, getting element text, how to simulate mouse hover over element, waiting for element/s, ... But found none or only partially usable tutorials, with little to no explanation. Does anyone have links to such?

I have already installed NodeJS, selenium webdriver and all browsers drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Selenium Docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html), you might get an idea how to do it.

Comment: You should try offering a solution with explanation.

Comment: @ Tapas Mahato: Still not as usable for a beginner. For example, do you perhaps know how would I do the following (Protractor) with Selenium Javascript: `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(browser.element(by.id('language')),5000).then(function() { browser.element(by.id('language').click(); });`. Mind that I use page objects, but for better overview I wrote element locator.

Answer (score 0):

are you loking for this?

http://webdriver.io/

check API and Developers Guide there, I think you will find all what you need

http://webdriver.io/api.html

http://webdriver.io/guide.html

Comment: No, more like this http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations, but with greater detail, with all available commands, examples, ... Btw, webdriver.io is fine and I currently use Protractor (pain to use for nonAngular pages).

Comment: What about something like this http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html  it looks similar to selenium docs you gave as an example.  Also you don't need to use protractor, we use cucumberjs :)

Comment: @Peter Grainger: I will have to check it later today to see, but it seems too different to me.